# OR operator usage in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `Or` operator in VBA. I'm not very familiar with this language, which you might be able to tell.

The following part of the code works just fine:

```
FirstRow = 2
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1
For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
If Cells(r, "K") <> 114 Then
    Rows(r).Delete
End If
Next r
```

It deletes the rows not containing the number 114. The problem is that I want to include the numbers 136 and 139 aswell. I want to keep only the rows containing 114, 136 or 139 in column K that is (plus the headline and summarizing row).

I've tried a few similar to:

```
FirstRow = 2
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1
For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
If Cells(r, "K") <> 114 Or _
   Cells(r, "K") <> 136 Or _
   Cells(r, "K") <> 139 Then
   Rows(r).Delete
End If
Next r
```

These codes just remove everything except the headlines and summarizing row.

What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```
Sub SouthEast()
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Show only South East")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Dim r As Long
        Dim FirstRow As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long

        FirstRow = 2
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        If Cells(r, "K") <> 114 Or _
            Cells(r, "K") <> 136 Or _
            Cells(r, "K") <> 139 Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
        Next r
    Else
        'Do nothing        
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `And` insted of `Or`, it works the same in any other programming language.

Comment: Embarrassing. Thank you. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `And` operator in this instance like this:

```
If Cells(r, "K") <> 114 And _
   Cells(r, "K") <> 136 And _
   Cells(r, "K") <> 139 Then
   Rows(r).Delete
End If
```

If you were to check for equality you would use `Or`.

Like this:

```
If Cells(r, "K") = 114 Or _
   Cells(r, "K") = 136 Or _
   Cells(r, "K") = 139 Then
   Rows(r).Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical logical mistake: you are talking about:

```
Not(
 (value == 114) OR
 (value == 136) OR
 (value == 139))
```

This is equal to:

```
Not(value == 114) AND
Not(value == 136) AND
Not(value == 139)
```

Which is equal to:

```
(value <> 114) AND
(value <> 136) AND
(value <> 139)
```

Comment: Good answer explaining the logical operation, but there is no `==` in VBA, it's a simple `=` :)

Comment: @Nacorid: you're so right, but the amount of times that I needed to explain that the `=` was an equality operator instead of a variable assignation, it's countless :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `And`

`Or` calls `TRUE` if *any* of the values are true

`And` calls `TRUE` if *all* of the values are true

```
Sub SouthEast()
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Show only South East")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Dim r As Long
        Dim FirstRow As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long

        FirstRow = 2
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
        If Cells(r, "K") <> 114 And _
            Cells(r, "K") <> 136 And _
            Cells(r, "K") <> 139 Then
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
        Next r
    Else
        'Do nothing        
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar with the above but i want to emphasize something details.

1. It s better to use *Option Explicit* to avoid declaration errors.
2. It is better to clearly indicates the sheet and the range you are working with.
3. In my opinion is better to use *.value*

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub SouthEast()

       Dim answer As Integer
       Dim r As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long

       answer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Show only South East")

       If answer = vbYes Then

           With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

               FirstRow = 2
               LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1

               For r = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1

                   If .Cells(r, "K").Value <> 114 And _
                       .Cells(r, "K").Value <> 136 And _
                       .Cells(r, "K").Value <> 139 Then
                       .Rows(r).Delete
                   End If

               Next r

           End With
       Else
           'Do nothing
       End If

   End Sub
   ```